# How to access the Tensor value?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am very new to Pytorch. While finding the value of a variable, this is how it shows

```
tensor(0.94091, device='cuda:0')
```

How to access the number, i.e, 0.94091?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .item() to get the value of size one tensor.